# Peticion POST externa

Tags: laravel-5

Estoy enviándole a PayU(Plataforma para hacer y recibir pagos online) variables por un formulario POST que al ser correctas me permiten generar el pago en su plataforma. Esto funciona correctamente.

Una de las variables que envío en ese formulario es `"urlConfirmation(http://hexamedia.co/edictosocc/public/confirmacion)"` que me dice: al dar la transacción aprobada (y si la da) le enviaremos unas variables que puede guardar en la BD por método POST a esa URLconfirmation que nos indico .

Entonces lo que hice fue:

1) Cree la ruta

```
Route::post('confirmacion','CompraController@confirmation')->name('edictos.confirmacion');
```

2) En el controlador tengo la función para agregar el dato que necesito en la BD

```
public function confirmation(Request $request)
         {
           $compra = new Compra;
           $data = $request->all();
           $compra->co_fullname = $data['nickname_buyer'];
           $compra->save();
         }
```

Sin embargo no funciona.

Creo que hace falta otorgarle permisos al Middleware para que reciba request externas.

Podrian guiarme en como hacer eso?

Answer (score 1):

Tenes que agregar la ruta en protected $except en el Middleware VerifyCsrfToken.php

```
protected $except = [
        'confirmacion',
    ];
```